# springboot 3 reactive cassandra keyspace DataStax config try to connect localhost

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra, aws-java-sdk, amazon-keyspaces, aws-devops

I'm trying to connect to amazon-keyspace AWS Casandra via my spring-boot-3 multi-module software but it tries to connect **localhost** / **endPoint=/127.0.0.1:9042** instead.
here is some of my build gradle

```
plugins {
    java
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.0.1" apply false
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.0"
    id("io.freefair.lombok") version "6.6.1"
}
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
dependencies {
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra-reactive")
implementation("software.aws.mcs:aws-sigv4-auth-cassandra-java-driver-plugin:4.0.8")
...
}
```

try diffrent application.yml file and add and remove some settings to see diffrence

`

```
#new settings
spring:
cassandra:
  keyspace-name: my-existing-keyspace
  schema-action: none
  config: keyspaces-application.conf
  local-datacenter: eu-north-1
  contact-points: cassandra.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com:9142
#Depricated one
spring:
  data:
    cassandra:
      keyspace-name: my-existing-keyspace
      schema-action: none
      config: keyspaces-application.conf
      local-datacenter: eu-north-1
      contact-points: cassandra.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com:9142`
```

and here it is my keyspaces-application.conf :

```
datastax-java-driver {

    basic.contact-points = [ "cassandra.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com:9142"]
    advanced.auth-provider{
        class = PlainTextAuthProvider
        username = "my existing username"
```

type here

```
        password = "my existing password"
    }
    basic.load-balancing-policy {
        local-datacenter = "eu-north-1"
        slow-replica-avoidance = false           
    }

    advanced.ssl-engine-factory {
        class = DefaultSslEngineFactory
        truststore-path = "/home/ec2-user/cassandra_truststore.jks"
        truststore-password = "my-truststore-password"
        hostname-validation = false
      }
}
```

but it tries to connect localhost 1

and here it is some logs:

```
`Error connecting to Node(endPoint=/127.0.0.1:9042, hostId=null, hashCode=3d061dd6), trying next node (ConnectionInitException: [s0|control|connecting...] Protocol initialization request, step 1 (OPTIONS): failed to send request (io.netty.channel.StacklessClosedChannelException))
  WARN 24461 --- [           main] onfigReactiveWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'myRepositoryImpl' defined in URL [jar:file:/home/ec2-user/my-service/my-container/build/libs/my-container-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/my-dataaccess-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/com/anything/MyRepositoryImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'myCasandraRepository' defined in ******.MyRepository defined in @EnableReactiveCassandraRepositories declared on ContainerApplication: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'reactiveCassandraTemplate' while setting bean property 'reactiveCassandraOperations'`


`Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'reactiveCassandraTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/cassandra/CassandraReactiveDataAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'reactiveCassandraTemplate' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'reactiveCassandraSession' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/cassandra/CassandraReactiveDataAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'reactiveCassandraSession' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'cassandraSession' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/cassandra/CassandraAutoConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.CqlSession]: Factory method 'cassandraSession' threw exception with message: Could not reach any contact point, make sure you've provided valid addresses (showing first 1 nodes, use getAllError`


`Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cassandraSession' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/cassandra/CassandraAutoConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.CqlSession]: Factory method 'cassandraSession' threw exception with message: Could not reach any contact point, make sure you've provided valid addresses (showing first 1 nodes, use getAllErrors() for more): Node(endPoint=/127.0.0.1:9042, hostId=null, hashCode=3d061dd6): [com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.connection.ConnectionInitException: [s0|control|connecting...] Protocol initialization request, step 1 (OPTIONS): failed to send request (io.netty.channel.StacklessClosedChannelException)]`
```

I am trying to connect amazon-keyspace aws casandra  via spring boot 3 application and datastax-v4
but it try to connect to **localhost**  **endPoint=/127.0.0.1:9042**
It should be posibbly I missed a config or may some config changed for spring boot 3 or need some changes for reactive settings

Answer (score 0):

Correct [configuration is](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.data.spring.cassandra.contact-points)

```
spring.cassandra.contact-points=host:port
```

I see you have

```yaml
spring:
cassandra:
  keyspace-name: my-existing-keyspace
  schema-action: none
  config: keyspaces-application.conf
  local-datacenter: eu-north-1
  contact-points: cassandra.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com:9142
```

you are having indentation problem. It should have been like below

```yaml
spring:
  cassandra:
    keyspace-name: my-existing-keyspace
    schema-action: none
    config: keyspaces-application.conf
    local-datacenter: eu-north-1
    contact-points: cassandra.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com:9142
```

if you do not give that tab character, configuration goes back to default 127.0.0.1:9042 and does not throw any exception.